# How can I fix this: User not able to view footer, if not authenticated

Tags: footer

I set up a custom footer in our internal SharePoint 2013 site, which displays fine, if the user is authenticated.  However, the user can not view the footer, if they are not logged in to the system.  Is there anyway to fix this, so the user views the footer whether or not he/she is logged into the system?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the user can see rest of the SharePoint site/page but not the footer when he is not authenticated?!!!

Comment: How has your "footer" been built-up?

Comment: Yes, Shashank Reddy Karam.  The visitor can see all other elements on the home page, and other pages, except the footer and the microfeed (authentication is set required to view this).  I placed the HTML footer code inside the oslo.html master, like normal, and it saved to the oslo.master, like normal.

Comment: Here is the location of the html footer code....

Comment: Here is the location of the html footer code.... between 
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false"/>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->         
<div class="wrapper" style="min-height: 100px; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -500; z-index: 100; background: #072b61; position:relative; bottom:0px; width:100%;">
<div class="footerO2"..................{FOOTER LINKS HERE]
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AuthenticatedUserDiv>-->

Comment: Place it outside the `SharePoint:AuthenticatedUserDiv`?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't display at all outside of that div.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided in your comment, your footer code is contained inside a `SharePoint:AuthenticatedUserDiv` which would trim it away from an anonymous user.

Move it outside of that div and it should appear for everyone regardless if they are logged in or not.

Comment: Thank you, Eric.  that was the first thing I tried this morning.  I moved it below the AuthenticatedUserDiv, then below the ScriptBlock div, then found a post to move it inside the s4-workspace, which I followed.  However, it is not displaying at all now.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Eric, are you familiar with versioning for Anonymous sites?  The solution we found was related to Major and Minor versions.  So, I wanted to ask if anyone could explain why changes to the master are visible only if it is published as a major version?

Comment: That is how it works, it is all permission related. Anonymous and Read users can only see versioned files that are at a major version level, 2.0, and if applicable have their content approval status set to Approved. Draft versions, 1.3, are only visible to those, typically, with contribute rights or higher.

Comment: Thank you so much, Eric.  This is my first experience with an Anonymous site, so you have helped me understand.  I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the challenges and proposed solutions for the O2 footer in the oslo.html (Masterfile):

.
.
.

```
[[[ master/html code goes here. but inside the ending div tags below is where it is suggested to put the footer code ]]....


<!-- The hidden place holders are below.  The highlighted one  ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole”     is where one techie suggested to place the footer -->
<div class="ms-hide">
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderNavSpacer" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                              <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->
                                            <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server" Visible="false"/>-->

<!-- The 10 ending divs are below -->

                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  <!-- end div class ms-tableRow  -->
                            </div>  <!-- div class ms-table ms-fullWidth -->
                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- end div class contentwrapper -->
                </div> <!-- end div class ms-tableRow -->


<!-- when the footer is here, before the body container tag ends, it works perfectly, but must be authenticated before you can view it because it is situated inside the authentication closing tag -->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
                            <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false"/>-->

[[[[[[ FOOTER CODE GOES HERE ]]]]]]

                            <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->     



            </div> <     <!-- end div id ms-belltown-table    class ms-table -->
        </div>           <!-- end body container -->

<!—One of the suggestions to place the footer inside the div id=s4-workspace tag (below).  However, it is also situated inside the authentication tag. -->

    </div>               <!-- end div id s4-workspace  -->



<!-- Below is the authentication closing tag -->                         

                            <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AuthenticatedUserDiv>-->

<!—below is the footer placeholder code – put the html code of the footer (links and style) inside these tags  -->          
<!— However, when placing the footer code here, outside of the authentication closing tag, it does not show up on the pages -- >

<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderFooter" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
                            <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PageFooter" AllowMultipleControls="false"/>-->

[[[[[[ FOOTER CODE GOES HERE ]]]]]]

                            <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->     


            <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:var g_Workspace = "s4-workspace";-->   

<!— And when placing the footer code here, between the scriptblock/workspace tag, it does not show up on the pages either -- >

            <!--SPM:</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what solution you are proposing.  It appears you have reorganized the code into one box, instead of the several boxes it required me to copy and paste into.  Please let me know if you have proposed a solution and I am just not seeing it.  Thank you!

Comment: After trial and error, we found the issue: Normally, CheckIn and CheckOut of oslo.html file when editing is not required. The changes usually commit immediately, without checking out or in, OR for both major or minor versions, after check-in.  But, when editing a custom footer in an Anonymous environment, the HTML master MUST BE checked out, then checked-in as a MAJOR version, for the edits to be visible to an anonymous user!  In other words, if the user is not authenticated, the changes will not be visible if not saved as a Major version. Not sure why?  Any input here is appreciated!!